# ios: NSInvalidArgumentException, unrecognised selector on prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c

**The situation:**

I've got three views named LogInView, CategoryRegistrationView, and BlueToothCheckerView. Both LogInView and CategoryRegistrationView can segue to BlueToothCheckerView.

BlueToothCheckerView itself can segue into two different views, depending on a string set by LogInView or CategoryRegistrationView.

LogInView does this just fine. A user can log in from LogInView, check if his Bluetooth connection is on in BlueToothCheckerView, and is then redirected to a view he won't see if he otherwise came in from CategoryRegistrationView.

CategoryRegistrationView has problems.

**The Problem:**

On click of the button to take me to BlueToothView, this error appears:

```
[BlueToothCheckerViewController setFromSegue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c935a4f80
```

A lot of posts online indicated that it's because BlueToothCheckerView is not set as the Custom Class for xib BlueToothView, but it is.

**The Code** (We'll be focusing on CategoryRegistrationView and BlueToothCheckerView to keep things short):

`CategoryRegistrationViewController.h` - Problem segment:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    NSLog(@"Segue Identifier: %@", [segue identifier]);

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CategoryRegistrationToBlueToothCheckerSegue"]) {
        BlueToothCheckerView *btcv = [segue destinationViewController];
        btcv.fromSegue = @"CategoryRegistrationToBlueToothCheckerSegue"; // <-- Error here
        NSLog(@"Something wrong here");
    }
}
```

Note: LogInViewController has the exact same code, with *btvc.fromSegue* set to "LoginToBlueToothCheckerSegue" instead.

`BlueToothCheckerView.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol BlueToothCheckerViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)skipPressed:(id)sender;
@end

@interface BlueToothCheckerView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<BlueToothCheckerViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *SkipButton;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* fromSegue;

- (IBAction)skipPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

`BlueToothCheckerViewController.h`

```
#import "BaseUIViewController.h"
#import "BlueToothCheckerView.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface BlueToothCheckerViewController : BaseUIViewController <BlueToothCheckerViewDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) BlueToothCheckerView *btcv;

@end
```

Both `BlueToothCheckerView` and `BlueToothCheckerViewController` at the very least show string *fromSegue*.

Here's a sample of how *fromSegue* is used, in `BlueToothCheckerViewController.m`:

```
- (void)skipPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Bluetooth already on");

    if ([self.btcv.fromSegue isEqual: @"LoginToBlueToothCheckerSegue"]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BlueToothCheckerToDashboardSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else if ([self.btcv.fromSegue isEqual: @"CategoryRegistrationToBlueToothCheckerSegue"]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BlueToothCheckerToWalkthroughSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

**What I Tried:**

I tried deleting the segue in question, and re-adding it. It didn't much. I also commented out the line `btcv.fromSegue = @"CategoryRegistrationToBlueToothCheckerSegue";`, and confirmed the program ran fine without it.

I also tried adding a cast to BlueToothCheckerController. Didn't work either.

In light of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170453/uiviewcontroller-throwing-unrecognized-selector-exception-on-prepareforsegue) answer, I also checked my Build Phases. Here's what it looks like, if it matters.

[image]

Any thoughts, please?

Comment: *BlueToothCheckerViewController* has no method named `setFromSegue:`.

Comment: @HotLicks, how / where do I set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is this:

```
BlueToothCheckerView *btcv = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Although you're saying that the destination controller is a `BlueToothCheckerView`, the error message says that it's really a `BlueToothCheckerViewController`.

Since the controller doesn't have the property, it fails.

Comment: I'm getting a `Property 'fromSegue' not found on object type BlueToothCheckerViewController`, before I even compile the code. `fromSegue` is created in BlueToothCheckerView, and the xib's custom class is also set to that. It is then delegated to BlueToothCheckerViewController.

Comment: I was answering the about the error you listed under "**The Problem:**".  In general, though, you have to set the property on an object of the type that **has** the property.  In other words, if you have a `BlueToothCheckerViewController ` and its view is a `BlueToothCheckerView ` and the view has the property, then you need to set it on the view.

Comment: Ah, that did it. I put `fromSegue` into `BlueToothCheckerViewController` and modified anything that called it. Thanks.